# AspNet core MVC – Lógica do CRUD na Controller, na Model ou Service

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Me deparei com uma dúvida, tenho um projeto bem simples aqui com três entidades, sendo elas Professor, Aluno e Turma.

Eu criei as classes na Model.
Exemplo

```
namespace coreSchoolSimple.Models
{
    public class Professor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Telefone { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Para mim fazer o CRUD, tenho três opções.

1-Se eu usar o VS 2017 para gerar a controller com views e EF, ele cria a controller já com a lógica de CRUD completo para mim, porem a logico fica dentro da Controller.

2- Criar a controller em branco, e a lógica do CRUD fica dentro da classe de cada entidade, exemplo: na classe Professor vai ter os métodos Create, Delete, Insert e List.

3- já nesta opção é criar uma pasta chamada service na raiz do projeto, e fazer as logicas dentro de uma classe nesta pasta, e usar essas classes como serviço para cada entidade, exemplo: ProfessorService.cs vai ter os métodos de crud. E uso ele como service.

A minha dúvida é:
Tem alguma diferença entre essas formas fora a questão de organização? Por exemplo performance ou boas práticas?

Raiz do Projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem diferença obviamente, se não tivesse seria a mesma coisa. Performance de forma geral não, boa prática não serve pra nada se não atende uma motivação específica, e sem caso concreto beira a opinião. Você tem alguma dúvida específica?

Comment: Sim, digamos q tenho vários outros métodos para fazer (além do crud) por exemplo calcularMediaNotas(), devo fazer na classe da entidade respectiva ou fazer numa outra classe de serviço, estou perguntando isso pq estou iniciando meus estudos, e quero fazer da maneira correta.

Comment: E como vamos saber se não entendemos todo o contexto do seu software? Por alguma razão você acha que existem respostas mágicas (eu já desconfiava por acreditar em boas práticas) então está querendo que alguém diga "faça assim e tudo será lindo", isto não existe. Não existe maneira correta sem entender o contexto que está trabalhando, isso só você sabe.

Comment: Qual contexto você não entendeu na minha pergunta? diga-me para q eu possa esclarecer.

Comment: Não tem o que entender, porque não existe um contexto, só você sabe o seu contexto.

Comment: Fechei como P. B. Opiniões por vários elementos extremamente subjetivos (a exemplo da resposta dada), mas daria para classificar como ampla e não clara, dada a falta de parâmetros e o assunto muito "conversa informal" (no bom sentido, por se tratar de algo para uma conversa e não Pergunta + Resposta objetiva) - Considerando que sua pontuação já permite, seria o caso de levantar estas dúvidas inicialmente no [chat da rede](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha), e à medida que o escopo centrar em problemas pontuais, elaborar perguntas separadas sobre cada um desses pontos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pois então, estas opções do Visual Studio de criar a Controller em cima de uma Model é boa para você não ter que criar as Actions e as Views do zero. No entanto, o que acontece é que o projeto web MVC nada mais é do que a camada de interface com o usuário do que outra coisa. O ideal geralmente é você criar, pelo menos, outros projetos ClassLibrary que vão representar a camada de Model e de Infraestrutura (acesso a dados). Isolando as camadas por responsabilidade (dados, model, serviço) fica mais fácil você modificar depois a tecnologia da camada de interface com usuário por exemplo, sem falar na manutenção do código.

O cenário abaixo seria uma customização do para seu projeto. Retirei bastante coisas do DDD, para simplificar:

1. Projeto Domain: contém as Entidades, Interfaces de serviço de domínio, por exemplo IProfessorService com as operações Insert, Delete, Edit, Delete, e Interfaces de acesso a dados com as operações da fonte de dados (banco de dados, API e etc.), classes com validações de regra de negócio.

   - Nas classes de Serviço de Domínio (por exemplo, ProfessorService.cs) você implementar as interfaces com as operações do CRUD e utiliza a classe de validação da regra de negócio. Nessa classe ProfessorService.cs você injeta a a interface de acesso a dados.
2. Projeto de Infraestrutura: contém as classes que implementam as interfaces de acesso a dados (definidas no projeto Domain). Tem toda a parte de comandos e opearações SQL (ou de outro repositório que você utilize como API).

No projeto MVC você utilizaria a interface IProfessorService (por injeção de dependência no Controller) e usaria todos os métodos do CRUD.

Em resumo: para projetos MVC muito pequenos, mas muito pequenos mesmo, talvez que vale a pena usar a estrutura que o Visual Studio monta na criação das Controllers. Mesmo assim, acho melhor pelo menos criar os projetos de Domain e Infra (acesso a dados) separado do projeto MVC. Acho que vale a pena "customizar" a arquitetura DDD para a realidade do projeto que você está mexendo.

Esses conceitos são bem longos para tratar aqui, mas dê uma olhada nos links:

Apesar de ser em MVC 5, este material tem bastante coisas sobre separação de camadas. Vale a pena ver: [separacao de camadas](https://www.eduardopires.net.br/2014/10/tutorial-asp-net-mvc-5-ddd-ef-automapper-ioc-dicas-e-truques/)

https://www.eduardopires.net.br/2017/12/10-boas-praticas-no-desenvolvimento-com-aspnet-core/

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/web/aspnet-architecture

Comment: Bom dia Raquel, edita sua resposta, ficou com textos repetidos, e queria agradecer pelo compartilhamento de informações.

Comment: Bom dia @Renan. Obrigada pelo retorno! Tem outro link que eu gostaria de compartilhar. Não ligue pelo fato de ser MVC 5, por que este material tem bastante coisas sobre separação de camadas. Vale a pena ver: [separacao de camadas](https://www.eduardopires.net.br/2014/10/tutorial-asp-net-mvc-5-ddd-ef-automapper-ioc-dicas-e-truques/)